# $\int_C \frac{\log z}{z-z_0} dz$ - Cauchy theorem with $z_0$ outside the interior of $\gamma$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let the domain $O=\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0)$, the point $z_0 \in O$ and the circle $\gamma=C(0,r<|z_0|)$ in the positive direction. Compute $\int_C \frac{\log z}{z-z_0} dz$. [image]

How do I solve the problem with the Cauchy theorem knowing that the point $z_0$ is outside the interior of $\gamma$? Do I have to use the primitive of $\log z$, i.e. $\log' z = \frac{1}{z}$?

Thank you to bear in mind that I have not yet seen the Residue theorem.

Comment: How are you trying to integrate over a path crossing a branch? I think that isn't even defined.

Comment: @Joanpemo How is it possible to solve this integral without using the Cauchy theorem?

Comment: My idea is to use a keyhole contour: before "closing" the circle at the negative real axis, "run" to the origin and do a circle around it to the other side, and then let things tend to the real axis. I'm not sure, though, whether this would yield something acceptable. Something like this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/67/KeyholeContourLeft.png

Comment: Are you able to do and / or sketch a solution?

Comment: Cauchy Theorem tells us that in that keyhole contour the integral equals zero as the integrand function is analytic in that simply connected domain. I'd love to deduce then that in the limit the value is also zero, but I really can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To evaluate the contour integral, we use a keyhole contour to avoid the branch cut.  Consider the integral

$$\oint_{C'} dz \frac{\log{z}}{z-z_0} $$

where $C'$ is the keyhole contour.  The contour integral is then

$$\int_C dz \frac{\log{z}}{z-z_0} + e^{i \pi} \int_1^{\epsilon} dx \frac{\log{x}+i \pi}{-x-z_0}+ i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^{-\pi} d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{\log{\epsilon}+i \phi}{\epsilon e^{i \phi} - z_0}+e^{-i \pi} \int_{\epsilon}^1 dx \frac{\log{x}-i \pi}{-x-z_0}$$

The third integral vanishes as $\epsilon \to 0$.  We can combine the second and fourth integrals to further simplify:

$$\int_C dz \frac{\log{z}}{z-z_0} - i 2 \pi \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x+z_0} $$

By Cauchy's theorem, the integral over $C'$ is zero.  Thus, when $z_0$ is exterior to the unit circle $C$:

> $$\int_C dz \frac{\log{z}}{z-z_0} = i 2 \pi \log{\left (1+\frac1{z_0} \right )} $$

**ADDENDUM**

From the above, it should be simple to evaluate the integral when $z_0$ is inside the unit circle.  By the residue theorem, when $z_0$ is interior to $C$,

$$\int_C dz \frac{\log{z}}{z-z_0} = i 2 \pi \log{\left (1+z_0 \right )} $$

Comment: In your fifth line, how is that integral $\;\int_C\;$ appearing there? And where does $\;C'\;$ kicks in? Thank you.

Comment: @Joanpemo: I was just stating the result.  The beginning of the analysis would be that $$\oint_{C'} dz \frac{\log{z}}{z-z_0} = i 2 \pi \log{z_0} $$

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to be a pest, specially since the asker apparently understood you already, but shouldn't then that plus sign after $\;\int_C\;$ in that line after "the countour integral is then..." be an equality sign? I also don't understand why that third integral vanishes as $\;\epsilon\to0\;$ . Thank you

Comment: @Joanpemo: 1) No, it should be clear that the second expression is equal to the integral over $C'$, 2) $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \epsilon \log{\epsilon}= 0$.

Comment: Do you use an extension by continuity on the $(- \infty,0)$ axis in your solution?

Comment: @RobertDavis: sorry, I do not know what you mean by "an extension by continuity"

Comment: A function $f$ is extended by continuity at $x_o$ if $\lim_{x \to x_0^+} f(x) =\lim_{x \to x_0^-} f(x) \not= f(x_0) $. I know the name of this concept in french, but it is not clear in english.

Comment: @RobertDavis: Then I'd have to say, not knowingly!  Sorry, I do not have a better answer to your question than that.  I am merely traversing both sides of the branch cut within the unit circle so I can express the desired integral in terms of something simpler.

Comment: The answer that my teacher gives us is $2\pi i \log z_0$. According to your answer, I know that this answer is false. I think he has used the simple Cauchy formula with the primitive of $\log ' z$. Is there a contradiction in this answer I can mention him? To know that he give us only the simple solution (not his resolution method).

Comment: @TajMohamedBandalandabad: what you can do is offer him a concrete example.  Convert the complex integral into a real integral using $z=e^{i t}$, compute the real integral and verify that the answer derived here is the correct one.

Comment: @RonGordon Small detail: The contour of the question is $|z| = r$, while you are integrating over $|z| = 1$. Easily changed by scaling. FYI: this answer is the topic of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702343/contour-integral-int-c-frac-log-zz-z-0-dz-contradiction).