# Contour integral - Use an example to contredict an answer

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

The answer that my teacher gives us is $2πi \log z_0$. I know that this answer is false according to the question [$\int_C \frac{\log z}{z-z_0} dz$ - Cauchy theorem with $z_0$ outside the interior of $\gamma$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694744/int-c-frac-log-zz-z-0-dz-cauchy-theorem-with-z-0-outside-the-interio/1694768?noredirect=1#comment3473302_1694768) and the answer given by Ron Gordon. I think he has used the simple Cauchy formula with the primitive of $\log′ z$. Is there a contradiction in this answer I can mention him? To know that he gives us only the simple solution (not his resolution method).

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher made a mistake. An easy way to see this is to fix the contour and then note that as $z_0\to \infty,$ the integrand $\to 0$ uniformly, hence the integral $\to 0.$ But your teacher's answer has the integral $\to \infty$ as $z_0\to \infty.$

Comment: I have no doubt that your answer is true, but I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you explain in details, regorously your method of resolution? :)